# Trying to deploy angular project on firebase - error 404

Tags: angular, firebase, http-status-code-404

Im trying to deploy my angular 17 app, but I got 404 error everytime. Tried different firebase.json settings, but the problem remained.
Here's my firebase.json -

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-west1"
    }
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}
```

[image: and structure - here]
any help would be appreciated, ready to provide more information if needed

Answer (score 0):

From the above screenshot it seems like there is nothing in your `dist` folder....the folder that your `firebase.json` says is your `hosting.public` location.  `hosting.public` is a value that is to point to the directory in your project where files are to be zip'ed up and sent to the Hosting CDN service.

I have not used Angular much but I suspect that you need to run a command such as `ng build .......` to cause Angular to build the distribution (the "bundle") of your app.  That should populate the `dist` folder, then you can run `firebase deploy --only hosting` and validate in the output that a number of files got uploaded.

Seems [this part of the Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#building-and-serving-from-disk) might be what  you want to look at?